# How to get data from three table without using joins and subquery in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have three table

```
emp(id, name)
product(id, productname)
sales(id,emp_id,product_id,saleprice)
```

1. List all the employee with total sales.
2. Fetch the employee with highest sales.

Note: I dont want to use joining and subquery, please suggest me better way.

Comment: a) Why don't you want to use JOIN and b) why do you think a solution without JOIN would be *better* than one with?

Comment: If you want the employee name you can avoid the use of JOIN keyword but you have to join the tables using the table keys in the where clause.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a join or a subquery?  That's like saying "I want to drive my car, but I don't want to run the engine or touch the controls".

Comment: Also, are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Your question is tagged with both tags.

Comment: if you don't need  emp name and product name the you can avoid join  otherwise you can't

Comment: @Brian That at least has a solution: switch gear to idle and push it down a hill. But the result may be as unsatisfactory as with the OP question ...

Comment: @Juan Implicit join (where syntax) has the same performance. I prefer to use explicit join [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you have to touch some of the controls to "switch gear to idle", so I reject your proposed solution :)  Regardless of idiom, "I don't want to use joining and subquery" doesn't make any sense in an RDBMS environment.

Comment: Your desire to avoid joins and subqueries is puzzling. Can you please [edit] your question to provide more information about your problem, so we can help you?

Comment: It seems the OP has no interest is telling us why they have this odd requirement.  I was quite intrigued.

Comment: I wonder if the OP was hoping  to avoid figuring out joins? Kinda like driving a car without figuring out the headlights.

Answer (score 0):

If you could refer to emp_id only then there is no need to use `JOIN` at all:

```
SELECT emp_id, SUM(salesprice) AS total_sales
FROM sales
GROUP BY emp_id
ORDER BY total_sales DESC  -- comment 2 lines to get answer for 1 question
LIMIT 1; -- MySQL version for SQL Server use `SELECT TOP 1`
```

Please note that if specific employee does not have any sales then it will be skipped. You won't get 0/NULL value for non existing data.

---

**EDIT:**

If you decide to use `JOIN` then:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, SUM(s.salesprice) AS total_sales
FROM emp e
LEFT JOIN sales s
  ON e.id = s.emp_id
GROUP BY e.id, e.name
ORDER BY BY total_sales DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this. But better way is use join statement.But as your requirement you can do like this. I think this is this easiest way and very simple query.

I have provided create table and sample data insert query.

**This is answer for your requirement**

```
-- 1.List all the employee with total sales.
select distinct E.Id,E.Name,P.Productname,S.saleprice from Sales S,Emp E,Product P
where E.Id=S.Emp_id and P.Id=S.Product_id
```

[See result for 1st question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nxkY.png)

```
-- 2.Fetch the employee with highest sales.
select S.Emp_id,E.Name,SUM(S.saleprice) AS TotalSalePrice from Sales S,Emp E
where E.Id=S.Emp_id 
Group By S.Emp_id,E.Name
```

[See result for 2nd question  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLt5N.png)

**This is create table and sample data insert querys which create for your requirement**

```
create table Emp
(
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](100)
 );

create table Product(
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [Productname] [nvarchar](100)
 );

create table Sales(
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [Emp_id] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Emp([Id]) ,
 [Product_id] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product([Id]) ,
 [saleprice] [int] NOT NULL 
 );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp] ([Name]) VALUES('Jone Doe')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp] ([Name]) VALUES('Micheal Oshea')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp] ([Name]) VALUES('Ish Thalagala')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp] ([Name]) VALUES('Mark Poull')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp] ([Name]) VALUES('Janne Marker')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([Productname]) VALUES ('Coca Cola')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([Productname]) VALUES ('Pepsi')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([Productname]) VALUES ('Tooth Brush')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([Productname]) VALUES ('Water Filter')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product]([Productname]) VALUES ('Playstation 4 pro')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(1,1,10)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(1,4,500)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(2,2,10)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(2,5,600)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(2,4,500)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(3,1,10)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(3,2,10)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(3,3,30)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(3,4,500)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(3,5,600)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(4,1,10)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(5,4,500)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sales]([Emp_id],[Product_id],[saleprice])VALUES(5,5,600)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `from Sales S,Emp E,Product P
where E.Id=S.Emp_id and P.Id=S.Product_id` *is* a JOIN operation, written in the old-timey comma join syntax.

Comment: @O.Jones agreed.But,About his requirement.This is the very simple way to that.Otherwise we can't get a correct result.